# how to record different values of a "flag" file

Tags: bash

I have a black-box system that periodically updates a single-line "flag" file. This single-line file takes, over the course of the system's life various different values, corresponding to the states of an FSM.

E.g. like "downloading", "validating", "posting", etc. At any given point in time the value is different so the software must be opening the "flag" file, truncating it, and writing the new single-line value.

How can I maintain a log of the succession of different values? I was thinking something like `tail -f` but with the ability to record the different values and with a way that's guaranteed not to mess with the file system when the software is updating of those values. A simple `tail -f` fails with "file truncated" after some time.

Comment: These questions though not exact duplicates are pretty close and definitely related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10454/is-it-possible-to-roll-a-symlink-to-a-new-file-without-affecting-any-open-file & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83443/using-tail-to-follow-daily-log-file-in-bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `tail -F` (note that it is capitalised), which will retry opening/reading the file if it fails.

From `man tail`:

```
   -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, 
          and --follow=descriptor are equivalent

   -F     same as --follow=name --retry

   --retry
          keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes
          inaccessible; useful when following by name, i.e., with
          --follow=name
```

If your version of `tail` doesn't have `-F` (which is equivalent to `tail -f=name --retry`), you could use inotify, and wait for close_write (`inotifywait` is part of [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/)):

```
file=foo

while inotifywait -qq -e close_write "$foo" >/dev/null; do
    cat "$foo"
done > log
```

`tail -F` should be preferred if available, because there is a race condition when using `inotifywait`.

Comment: `tail -F` is available but I can't get rid of the file truncated messages, even with `tail -q -F`. Also I think `tail -F` mangles the output somehow if certain states are written and overwritten very quickly. So I used the solution with `inotifywait -qq` together with a `> /dev/null` for the `close_write` to get rid of the "CLOSE" messages and an extra `echo` to get values on separate lines.